# SSIS Visual Basic - Single Quote in Path name

Tags: ssis

I have a Visual Basic step in my SSIS package that goes and gets a file listing from a directory that the user provides. This step works great most of the time, but when the user provides a path that has a single quote in it the step fails with an error.

The path being used:
S:\Invoices - Miscellaneous\invoices rec'd from Customer\12.17.14

Generates error: 
Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'd'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Below is the code I am using for the step. However, one thing I should point out is that using xp_cmdshell is out of the question as we are not able to use that in this environment.

```vb
Public Sub Main()

    Dim SourcePath As String

    SourcePath = Dts.Variables("SourcePath").Value

    Dim SQLStr As String    'SQL string to hold the root query
    Dim ConnString As String
    ConnString = "Data Source=SQLPROD;Initial Catalog=Customer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection()
    Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand()
    SQLConn.ConnectionString = ConnString
    SQLConn.Open() 'open connection
    SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn
    'write root file list
    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(SourcePath)
    Dim fi As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles
    Dim f As IO.FileInfo

    'list the names of all files in the specified directory
    For Each f In fi
        SQLStr = "INSERT into T_FILE_LIST(File) VALUES  ('" + di.ToString + "\" + f.ToString.Trim + "')"
        SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
        SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    SQLConn.Close()
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

Any help you can provide to help me solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a parameterized query instead of string concatenation. This will handle single quotes in values, and also avoid the possibility of SQL injection attacks. Something like this:

```vb
'list the names of all files in the specified directory
SQLStr = "INSERT into T_FILE_LIST(File) VALUES (@File)"
SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr
SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarChar)
For Each f In fi
    SQLCmd.Paramaters("@File").Value = IO.Path.Combine(di.ToString, f.ToString.Trim)
    SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```